# Clicking a website button (Chrome) that has no ID

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I am trying to automate a login process along with other things. I found this script somewhere but the button I'm trying to click has no ID.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "https://members.merchinformer.com/login"
    set theTab to tab 1 of window 1
    repeat
        if (loading of theTab) is false then exit repeat
    end repeat
    set theURL to URL of theTab
    if theURL contains "login" then
        execute theTab javascript "document.getElementById('login-button').click();"
    end if
    end tell
```

I tried a bunch of methods to click it but with no success. Any way around it?

Comment: If you are trying to click the **Sign In** _button_ at that **URL**, then this works for me: `tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-block btn-custom waves-effect waves-light')[0].click();"`

Comment: Thanks! It works (it clicks) but it acts as if my credentials are not there (saying "Please fill in this field" when it's already filled. If I double click on an empty space inside the webpage and run the script again, it logs me in. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

This script is the one that clicks it:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    tell active tab of front window to ¬
        execute javascript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-block btn-custom waves-effect waves-light')[0].click();"
```

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in answers.